# Dash shows programs behind

Tags: unity-dash

Recently when I have been opening my dash the programs that I have open behind them will flash through. I have no idea how to fix this. thanks

Comment: You should add more info such as - What ubuntu release?, - All programs or just some?, & are you using the static or no blur option?

Answer (score 0):

You can install UnSettings typing the following in the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:diesch/testing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unsettings
```

Then open UnSettings, go to Dash tab and in Blur select Static Blur, if you wish you can choose No Blur too. This may fix your problem.

Comment: In 12.10 the `static blur` Will cause apps windows that are re-drawing to flash thru the Dash.`So that could be the issue & not a good option. (known unfixed bug

Comment: I think that you should report a bug at LaunchPad. I can't help you more than this because I don't know any other way to overcome this problem, but at LaunchPad they can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running 12.10 an an Asus N56VJ and lately the dash pops up for no apparent reason and won't go away, and doesn't have a close button.  Suspect it has something to do with the WAY too sensitive touch pad.  Will try changing the blur option - UnSettings looks like a useful program.